# Bootstrap date time picker not allowing user to type time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have a scenario where I use Bootstrap Datetimepicker to select time, but when I manually type the time, even in correct format, it changes to 12:00 AM on date picker close

Here is my datetimepicker:

```
$('#ShiftStart').datetimepicker({
    minDate: actualDate,
    maxDate: maxDate,
    useCurrent: false,
    format: 'hh:mm A',
    defaultDate:moment(startTime),
    stepping: 15
});

$('#ShiftEnd').datetimepicker({
    minDate: actualDate,
    maxDate: maxDate,
    format: 'hh:mm A',
    defaultDate:moment(startTime),
    stepping: 15
});
```

Even if I bind an `onfocusout` event to set the value of the datetimepicker it doesn't change when the picker closed.

```
$("#ShiftStart").focusout(function (e) {
    //here it is defaulted again to 12:00 AM
    var time = $('#' + e.target.id).val();
    $('#' + e.target.id).attr('data-time', actualDate + ' ' + time);
    $('#' + e.target.id).attr('value', actualDate + ' ' + time);
    $('#' + e.target.id).val(time)
});
```

Any work around on this.

```js
var actualDate = $('#ActualDate').val();
var maxDate = $('#MaxDate').val();
var startTime = $('#StartTime').val();
$('#ShiftStart')
  .datetimepicker({
    minDate: actualDate,
    maxDate: maxDate,
    useCurrent: false,
    format: 'hh:mm A',
    defaultDate: moment("12/27/2017"),
    stepping: 15
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>


 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
 
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input id="ActualDate" type="hidden" value="12/27/2017">
<input id="MaxDate" type="hidden" value="12/28/2017">
<input id="StartTime" type="hidden" value="12/27/2017 8:00:00 AM">
<input class="form-control timepicker valid" data-val="true" data-val-genericcompare="Start time must be earlier than end time" data-val-genericcompare-comparetopropertyname="ShiftEnd" data-val-genericcompare-operatorname="LessThan" data-val-required="The Start Time field is required."
  id="ShiftStart" name="ShiftStart" style="max-width : none;  border : 1px solid #cccccc;" type="text" value="12/27/2017 12:00 AM" data-time="12/27/2017 12:00 AM" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="ShiftStart-error" aria-invalid="false">
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Will provide. i'll edit my question

Comment: Please fix the console errors

Comment: Fixed! its testable now even if the css are not applied properly

Comment: Does my answer here help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828449/bootstrap-datepicker-js-using-todays-date-when-date-cleared/45841224#45841224

Comment: The plugin i am referring to is https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 2):

The datetimepicker defaults back to `12:00 AM` even if you select the value from the picker (not only manually type), I think this is a bug of the the lastest versions of the component.

Anyway, there are a couple of things to fix in your code. As the [`date([newDate])`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) states :

> Takes `string`, `Date`, `moment`, `null` parameter and sets the components model current moment to it. [...]
>
> **Parsing of the newDate parameter is made using moment library with the `options.format` and `options.useStrict` components configuration.**

So [`minDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#mindate), [`maxDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#maxdate) and  [`defaultDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate) are strings parsed using [`format`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format) option (`hh:mm A` in your case) and this will produce wrong values, use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) instead (e.g. `defaultDate: moment("12/27/2017", 'MM/DD/YYYY')`).

Even the `value` property in the HTML is parsed using format, `12/27/2017 12:00 AM` does not match `hh:mm A` so I've removed it in my snippet.

Here a working example using version `4.17.37` of the datetimepicker:

```js
var actualDate = $('#ActualDate').val();
var maxDate = $('#MaxDate').val();
var startTime = $('#StartTime').val();
$('#ShiftStart')
  .datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment(actualDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
    maxDate: moment(maxDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
    useCurrent: false,
    format: 'hh:mm A',
    defaultDate: moment("12/27/2017", 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
    stepping: 15
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<input id="ActualDate" type="hidden" value="12/27/2017">
<input id="MaxDate" type="hidden" value="12/28/2017">
<input id="StartTime" type="hidden" value="12/27/2017 8:00:00 AM">
<div class="row">
  <div class='col-sm-6'>
    <input class="form-control timepicker valid" data-val="true" data-val-genericcompare="Start time must be earlier than end time" data-val-genericcompare-comparetopropertyname="ShiftEnd" data-val-genericcompare-operatorname="LessThan" data-val-required="The Start Time field is required."
  id="ShiftStart" name="ShiftStart" style="max-width : none;  border : 1px solid #cccccc;" type="text"  data-time="12/27/2017 12:00 AM" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="ShiftStart-error" aria-invalid="false">
  </div>
</div>
```

Side thoughts:

- Since you are using `hh:mm A` format, you can probably just manage time and get rid of `minDate` and `maxDate` (in your example you are limiting to a single given day)
- If you want to do something when the components hides use [`dp.hide`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dphide) event.

Comment: yeah thats the main reason it doesn't behave the way i want, i have solved that issue using dp.hide and put data attribute to it. but the last problem i have is typing on the text

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because `minDate` is reseting the field value to the current date at midnight (probably the default time), and similarly `maxdate` probably also sets it to midnight by default.

Remove `minDate: actualDate` and `maxDate: maxDate` from the initialisation:

```
<input id="ActualDate" type="hidden" value="12/27/2017">
<input id="MaxDate" type="hidden" value="12/28/2017">
<input class="form-control timepicker valid" data-val="true" data-val-genericcompare="Start time must be earlier than end time" data-val-genericcompare-comparetopropertyname="ShiftEnd" data-val-genericcompare-operatorname="LessThan" data-val-required="The Start Time field is required."
    id="ShiftStart" name="ShiftStart" style="max-width : none;  border : 1px solid #cccccc;" type="text" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="ShiftStart-error" aria-invalid="false">

<script>
    var actualDate = $('#ActualDate').val();
    var maxDate = $('#MaxDate').val();
    $('#ShiftStart').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false,
        format: 'hh:mm A',
    });
</script>
```

In reply to your comment, you can pass in the `maxDate` parameter like this:

```
maxDate: new Date('2017', '12', '27', '03', '30', '00', '00')
```

Which i guess you will need to build from the `maxDate` string. Note that to get this working I had to remove the `defaultDate` parameter from the snippet in your question.

Comment: Works as expected but how will i set the max date of the widget since i need to control the min and max values

Comment: i will be trying the updated answer, but i need to get the date on an input since it will be posted from a controller

Comment: since we also have to set the start time on the date picker thats why we need the startTime value

Comment: @EduCielo Yes, you should be able to split the datetime you get from the controller and then use the parts to build the required `Date` (as shown in updated answer). You should be able to use a similar approach for `defaultDate` and `maxDate`.

Comment: okay will try that and will accept the answer. but is there something wrong with moment here? as i observe, if you use moment() it will default to the current date.

Comment: @EduCielo I don't think the issue is with `moment`, as it still works using the `new Date` solution and setting `defaultDate` to `moment`. The documentation for this plugin could definitely be improved upon